# Z-index is not working; can't figure out why.

Tags: html, wordpress, css, z-index

I have a test environment, and the z-index is not working for some reason for the website. I have tried position: relative; on most elements but not sure why is it not working.

Since it was made with a visual builder, the DOM structure is quite messy.

http://104.236.219.66/reachchina/

This is the website.

This is the part in question:

[image: The part in question]

It's in the sections with the card: the cards are not on the top of the orange "spilled ink" background, and the ink hovers over the cards.

Any idea why is it not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is always good to put your code here. Can you show the code for the z-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one div which is the container of the cards,
and one div which is the container of the stain.

If you want to make sure the card container is above the stain container using `z-index`, you need to specify it. Using `position: relative/absolute/fixed;` only activates the functionality of `z-index`, but it is set to 0 as default.

**To solve this, just add `z-index: 1;` to the card container.**

Unfortunately, You have not supplied an editable demo; the div that you should add `z-index: 1;` to is `.vc_row wpb_row.vc_row-fluid`, one div above `#services-section`.

You can also check out the demo, hope it best reflects your issue:

```css
#circle {
  /* this is the required property */
  z-index: 1;
}


#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 150px;
  margin: 50px;
  
  position: relative;
}


#square {
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #7db620;
  top: 200px;
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id="circle"></div>
    
  <div id="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a height fixed in css 
`.card-text.home p {
    height: 180px;
}`

you have to change it to min-height and set your box height as below:

`.card-text.home p {
    min-height: 180px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Itay Ganor wrote perfect answer above. He described the issue with a fine detail and simplified it by a general example.

I have tried to write my answer based on the page source. Follow the following instructions and it should work for you.

1. CSS Code to put in theme's panel or child theme's style.css:

   `.ult-carousel-wrapper .slick-slider { z-index: 1; }`
2. Clear the cache.
3. See the page again.

---

**Browser Code View**

[image: code view]

---

**Browser Front View**

[image: front-end display]